# Alfresco 4.2 CMIS content download URL asking for authentication?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am using CMIS 1.0 in alfresco 4.2 to create content download URL as below. I am rendering this URL on custom share page.

`http://myserver/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/content/spp.log?id=db88f5b8-cf95-40b5-9880-bf953648788c;1.1`

But it asks for user credentials. I tried to use another way but it also asks for username & password.

`http://myserver/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/entry?id=db88f5b8-cf95-40b5-9880-bf953648788c;1.1`

Is there any way I can download content without getting username/password popup?

Comment: Can adding alfresco ticket help?

Comment: Will the user already be logged into Share? If so, why not request the URL via the Share-Alfresco proxy, which handles the auth for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appended ticket to cmis atompub url and it works.

```
http://myserver/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/content/spp.log?id=db88f5b8-cf95-40b5-9880-bf953648788c;1.1&alf_ticket=TICKET_121Y8467435345
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of the file you want is "spp.log", then the URL to experiment with should be as follows to the best of my knowledge:

```
https://myserver/share/proxy/alfresco/cmis/i/db88f5b8-cf95-40b5-9880-bf953648788c/content/spp.log
```